# How to get the info into an Object

Tags: java, android, object

I have an `Object` in java (Android). If I print this object in Logcat, I can see 2 `String`s. Now, I need extract the `String`s. How?

```
listaFound.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {

            Object a = myAdapter.getAdapter().getItem(myItemInt);

            Log.d("tututu", "onItemClick: "+a.toString());

    }
});
```

The Response of log is:

> onItemClick: Neo3600

9C:04:73:81:F5:94

I need to get the Neo3600 and MAC adress strings.

Comment: Of what type are the contents of the adapter? I guess its some kind of class so cast 'a' to the type stored in the adapter. Or provide more code.

Comment: show the code of your adapter please

Comment: This is the adapter:  mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the adapter: mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" +
>   device.getAddress());

According to your comment above, the following should work:

```
// the (String) cast may be unnecessary depending on your implementation
String device = (String) myAdapter.getAdapter().getItem(myItemInt);
String[] nameAndAddress = device.split("\n");

String name = nameAndAddress[0];
String macAddress = nameAndAddress[1];
```